# Compilation error of C/C++ in Eclipse

Tags: c, build, include-path

I am trying to compile a code that has a include directory with some header files in it.
One header file is referenced as:

```
#include <include/A/example.h>
```

In one of the files.
I also have added the correct path of the folder that has `example.h` in the Eclipse:
`Project -> Properties -> Includes`

However I get this error when I try to build:

> fatal error: home/TJ/workspace/myProject/include/A/example.h: No such file or directory

Does anybody know why I get this error?

Thanks

Comment: `home/TJ/workspace/myProject/include/A/` Well, is it there or is it not?

Comment: Does it still happen if you replace the <> with ""

Comment: yes: home/TJ/workspace/myProject/include/A/ is there,

Comment: yes it still happens if I use ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the directory **/home/TJ/workspace/myProject** to the path, and not something else, such as **home/TJ/workspace/myProject** (note the missing leading slash) or **/home/TJ/workspace/myProject/include/A**?

Also, remember that <> in the #include directive means standard include files, so maybe you should use ""?

Comment: Yes I have added  /home/TJ/workspace/myProject to the path., and changing <> to "" does not have any effect.

Comment: And the file example.h is in the include/A subdirectory? And no mistakes with uppercase and lowercase somewhere? And no spaces inserted somewhere?

Comment: yes to all. This is on Linux, is there anything different on Linux?